# argument in system call

Tags: ruby

I was reading the doc of Ruby's `system` method [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). If I put in the option `-P /public/google` (specifying the directory for downloading), does that count as one argument or two arguments, or either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It counts as two.  Since there's a space in between the two, the shell sees it and splits it as `-P` and `/public/google` (if you've worked with arguments, even in ruby, the shell would pass those in as separate arguments to the script).

Comment: drderp, thanks for your answer! What do you mean by "if you've worked with arguments, even in ruby"?

Comment: @MikaH. In ruby, and in most other programming languages, if you run the script from command line like `some_file some args` or `ruby -- some_file.rb some args`, you'll be able to access those arguments through an array of some sort.  In ruby's case, it's `ARGV`.

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends which form of system you use.  If you pass a command string, ala:

```
system 'somecmd -P /public/google'
```

The command string will be interpreted through the shell which will parse it, tokenizing on whitespace resulting in two arguments to somecmd.  Likewise if you use the argument list form and you break the string up into whitespace delimited tokens, like:

```
system 'somecmd', '-P', '/public/google'
system *%w{ somecmd -P /public/google }
```

But if you use the argument list form, and send `-P /public/google` as a single argument it will appear to somecmd as a one argument with embedded whitespace:

```
system 'somecmd', '-P /public/google'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would `system 'somecmd', '-P /public/google'` (the version with one argument) yield the same result as `system 'somecmd -P /public/google'` (a version with two arguments)?

Comment: @MikaH. Results really depends on how sensitive `somecmd` is to arg tokenization and how the meaning changes; in general, getopts style option interpretation may treat `'-P /public/google'` quite differently than `'-P','/public/google'`.  `echo` might not care while `touch` would.